# Ubuntu 23.10 certbot: Unable to obtain certificate from root ISRG Root X2

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Due to internal security policies I need an P384r1-only certificate chain. I use `certbot` 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 23.10. From my understanding

```
certbot certonly -v \\
   -a apache -i None \\
   --cert-name <my-cert-name> \\
   -d <my-domain> \\
   --deploy-hook '<reload-command-here'> \\
   --key-type ecdsa --elliptic-curve secp384r1 \\
   --preferred-chain 'ISRG Root X2'
```

should do the trick. However, I get the error

```
Certbot has been configured to prefer certificate chains with issuer 'ISRG Root X2',
but no chain from the CA matched this issuer. Using the default certificate chain instead.
```

The result is a subscriber certificate with a ECDSA P384r1 key signed by a RSA 2048 intermediary CA certificate which in turn is signed by the RSA 4096 RSA root certificate "ISRG Root X1".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/#intermediate-certificates but per the link there for now they still use ECDSA intermediate E1 and ECDSA X2 _cross-signed by RSA X1_, which you'll have to patch manually. [It does look like they recently made some progress](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/isrg-root-x2-submitted-to-root-programs/149385) on X2 inclusion in root programs so they might sometime soon be offering pure-ECDSA through the normal ACME/certbot method.

Comment: On that same page the intermediary certificate E1 and the root certificate X2 are also listed. They are marked as "active, but limited availability". I wonder what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: That's described on the page at the link ('allowlisted accounts') I pointed you to

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a certificate signed by E1, which is signed by ISRG ROOT X2 you have to be in the allowlist for E1 certificates. Here is a webpage that might interest you: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ecdsa-availability-in-production-environment/150679